# How to tell ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings to pull specific connection string

Tags: .net, vb.net, console-application

I'm using some Microsoft sample code and they have an example of using ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings to pull a series of connection strings from the app.config and allow an individual to choose the string they want. I don't need the ability to choose, I just want to get the specific named connection string I have defined. Something like (yes, I know this isn't real code):

```
Configuration.ConnectionStrings.Select("myconnection")
```

Is this possible? If not, how should I pull in a single connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

```
      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["my_connection"].ConnectionString
```