# ASP.NET System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, connection, connection-string

I have the following code

```
private string conn(string name)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[String.Format("{0}ConnectionString", name)].ConnectionString;
    }
```

But I keep getting the error below on the return statement.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Can you please tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: Please make sure you setup connectionstring in web.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks for connection string named name + "ConnectionString".
It look's your web.config does not have connection string with this name.
Add connection string with generated name or change the code like this:

```
    private string conn(string name)
    {
        var coll = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[String.Format("{0}ConnectionString", name)];
        if (coll != null)
        {
            return coll.ConnectionString;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error arises if connectionstring return null, means you not setup connectionstring which normally setup in web.config file under

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionString" connectionString="Server=  (local);Database=sampledb;Trusted_Connection=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if the name passed in parameter to your method is null ??

You should look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293603/how-to-tell-configurationmanager-connectionstrings-to-pull-specific-connection-s), and other answers already provided on SO.